# Enum and their Values

Tags: c++, enums

What would be the value of Field.Format("%04d", ErrorCode) in the procedure below if the AErrorCode is ERR_NO_HEADER_RECORD_FOUND_ON_FILE?

Somewhere in a .h file:

```
enum AErrorCode
{
    ERR_UNKNOWN_RECORD_TYPE_CODE = 5001,
    ERR_NO_HEADER_RECORD_FOUND_ON_FILE,
    ERR_DUPLICATE_HEADER_RECORD_FOUND,

    ERR_THIRD_PARTY_LETTER_RECORD_HAS_A_ZERO_REFERRAL_AMOUNT = 5101,    

    ERR_CALL_OCA_UNKNOWN_PROBLEM = 5999
};
```

In some procedure:

```
void TADataset::SetErrorStatus(AErrorCode ErrorCode)
{
    NDataString Field;
    Field.Format("%04d", ErrorCode);
    AckRecord.SetField("oca_error_stat", "E");
    AckRecord.SetField("error_cd", Field);
}
```

Comment: To be pedantic, you should have a cast as in `Field.Format("%04d", static_cast<int>(ErrorCode));`.  Technically, `enum`s don't have to be the same size as an `int`, though they typically are in most implementations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 ERR_NO_HEADER_RECORD_FOUND_ON_FILE == 5002
```

---

If you don't specify any value at all, it starts at `0` and increments the next element in the `enum`. If you specify a value, then it starts incrementing starting by the next element. Unless you reset the counter again by specifying another value for a successor element.

Comment: It increments using whatever was previously defined + 1.

Comment: starts with 0, increments of 1, unless you specify the next value, then continue incrementing

Answer (score 2):

According C++ Standard 7.2/1:

> <...>If the first enumerator has no initializer, the value of the corresponding constant is zero. **An enumerator-definition without an initializer gives the enumerator the value obtained by increasing the value of the previous enumerator by one.**

It means that `ERR_NO_HEADER_RECORD_FOUND_ON_FILE` equal to `ERR_UNKNOWN_RECORD_TYPE_CODE+1`.